# jQuery referencing a selector as a variable

Tags: jquery

I am storing a div element to a variable, then set its inner html:

```
var myelement = $("#myelement");
myelement.html("<b></b>");
```

I can set the text within the  element as follows:

```
$("#myelement " + " b").html(“whatever");
```

How do you rewrite the line above to use the variable instead?  The code below results in an error: "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] b"

```
$(myelement + " b").html(“whatever");
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
myelement.find("b").html("whatever");
```

Since `myelement` is a jQuery object the string concatenation `myelement + " b"` will result in `[object Object] b`, which is an invalid selector syntax, so it will throw an error saying

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]
>   b

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) for your selector:

```
$('b', myelement).html('whatever');
```

If you really want to concatenate `' b'` onto the selector, you could also do:

```
$(myelement.selector + ' b').html('whatever');
```

Comment: Excellent answers, and both made alot of sense, but I preferred the second method because it is more readable to me, thanks once again.

Comment: @CarolineBeltran the [selector](http://api.jquery.com/selector/) property is deprecated as it may not always give the correct result... don't use it

Comment: @Arun P Johny, I visited the link and did see the find method being faster. The selector property makes more sense to me since the syntax is very similar to how it would be done in CSS. Thank you for telling me about the depreciated status.